# jQuery Tabbed Ajax content

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

So I need to make 3 tabs with query (got this part down), but each of them needs to retrieve filter-able data through an Ajax request. Basically the page is setup with a static div on the left with the filter in it, and then on the right the tabs change according to which one you pick.

I'm just wondering what would be the best method of grabbing the ajax content and putting it into each tab?

I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Use jquery tabs http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ its already support ajax ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward if I understand your question correctly. For instance, let's assume you want to retrieve a static webpage and simply insert all the content of that webpage into your container div...

```
$('#tab1').click(function(){
    //Fetch a webpage (via GET) and load into 'result'
    $.get('/path/to/stuff.htm',function(result){
        //Replace content of container with result
        $('#containerDiv').html(result);
    });
});
```

It's really that simple. If you need a piece of the result (such as extracting CDATA from an XMLRPC request), then you can simply load the *result* as a jQuery object, find the element, and then load that... like so...

```
$('#tab1').click(function(){
    //Fetch a webpage (via GET) and load into 'result'
    $.get('/path/to/stuff.htm',function(result){
        //Make result a jQuery obj
        result = $(result);
        //Replace content of container with result
        $('#containerDiv').html(result.find('mycdata').text());
    });
});
```

I should also note - if you have an XML result that is wrapped in CDATA, always read it as .text() even if you are inserting it as html. If the result isn't wrapped in CDATA, read it as .html().

UPDATE:
If you need to send extra data to the server (such to sort ASC or DESC), you might do this...

```
$('#tab1').click(function(){
    //Fetch a webpage (via GET) and load into 'result'
    $.get(
        '/path/to/service', 
        { sort:'ASC', startDate:'2012-04-01', endDate:'2012-04-08'}, 
        function(result){
            //Replace content of container with result
            $('#containerDiv').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Okay so that seems pretty good, but I need extra functionality. Basically I need the filter to update the ajax request aswell. Say I only want to grab results from the database that are a week old, I need to update each time the filter changes, etc.

Comment: In that case, you just need to send extra data with the request. I'll update the answer with an example...

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can access those javascript properties from your PHP with $_GET or $_REQUEST. For instance, $startDate = $_GET['startDate']

Comment: Okay. Let's say instead of grabbing different results every time I update the filter, I just grab one set of ALL different possible results, and then when I filter I'm just using already grabbed data. How would I store that data in jQuery?

Comment: The best way is probably to encode your results as JSON (use json_encode() in your PHP) and then pass it back to your JavaScript and store it in a JS global variable. If you need persistence (beyond that one page), you'll need to either cache the result server-side or store the JSON it in a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. Basically what I did was create functions that were called on the click of each nav object (to change the tabs), and then just did $(".container-div").html(ajax data here) for each request. And then, on the change or slide of each filter I simply called the function again and it sent it different variables, therefore updating the div with new values!
Working wonderfully!